# How does Mac OS X 10.7 detect different displays?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro, display

I have a Macbook Pro with Mac OS X 10.7, and an external display screen attached to my Macbook, which is working fine.
Sometimes, I have to switch the second display to a projector (because I want to give a presentation).

Those settings (e.g. arrangement, resolution) are different from my external display screen. In 90% of the cases, Mac OS X knows which arrangement/resolution I want, depending on the type of external screen; in 10% of the cases, it's mixing up the configurations and I have to manually edit the configuration again.

Can I see somewhere what configuration is attached to a certain display?
Why does Mac OS X mix the configuration settings between my external display screen and my projector?

Comment: Look in the ColorSync Utility.app in your Utility folder, there the profiles for the displays are saved, and it shows which one is used for what.

Comment: It depends. More details are really needed regarding your device. Some models simply have more than one GPU.

Comment: Is the external display on when you connect it?

Answer (score 1):

1) You should be able to see these configurations in System Preferences > Display. I believe you go to to Layout (or could be called mirroring).

2) OS X displays two Display panels so you know which panel is attached to which screen.

If the Display options don't allow you to pick a resolution, change the Resolution from "Best for XX display", that will allow you to pick a supported, lower, resolution.

Comment: 1) I can see the current configuration, but not other configurations (when I attach my external LCD screen, I cannot see the configuration of my projector)
2) yes, but it's showing an incorrect display

Comment: So the additional panel says something along the lines of Generic LCD?

Comment: @ squarefrog: what do you mean with your last question?

Comment: In the additional display config panel, it should say the name of the display at the top. I'm asking if it says Generic LCD or something similar?

Comment: @ squarefrog: it was saying the name of the projector, but it should have said the name of my LCD screen

Comment: OK So it looks like it doesn't recognise your new LCD screen. In that case what you'd want to do is try and force OS X to discover the change in screens. In Display preferences do you have a button that states Detect Displays?

Comment: @ squarefrog: yes, I have this button. I will try it, next time I have the issue

Answer (score 0):

You might want to investigate a third-party solution.

I would try [SwitchResX](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8355/switchresx) (Macupdate link) as it claims to be able to save the resolution better than OS X can on it's own.

I do not own this software.